# How to search data in firebase with firebase gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rubygems

I would to search for data in my firebase database that I connected to my ruby on rails server through the following gem

https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby

I see that the supported functions are

```
set(path, data, query_options)
get(path, query_options)
push(path, data, query_options)
delete(path, query_options)
update(path, data, query_options)
```

But how do I search with a search text?

I would like to do something like

```
User.where(email: params[:email], password: params[:password])
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The Realtime Database has limited query capabilities. It looks like the Ruby wrapper allows you to specify query options that would match to the [filtering capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) of the Firebase Realtime Database REST API, but you won't be able to do complex queries like filtering by two fields at once as in your example.

You might want to look into [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) as an alternative with richer querying capabilities (but still supporting realtime).

*Note:* I know it was just an example, but you should never store passwords in plaintext! [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) can give you full user management capabilities that are secure and handle all that stuff for you :)